# error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/branch_name': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/branch_name': reference broken

Tags: git

While I was working, all of a sudden I faced this issue while trying to git commit or any action.

```
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/branch_name': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/branch_name': reference broken
```

even when I try to switch to other branch & try to perform some operation, I face some other issue related to this above.

```
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'ORIG_HEAD': cannot lock ref 'ORIG_HEAD': unable to resolve reference 'ORIG_HEAD': reference broken
```

Answer (score 0):

After making all the research I have done the below & it solved the issue. Hope this helps!

1. `error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/branch_name': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/branch_name': reference broken`

   - Switch to Master branch & follow the commands
   - `git branch -d branch_name`
   - Then you would be getting the below message

     error: The branch 'branch_name' is not fully merged.
     If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D branch_name'.
   - `git branch -D  branch_name`
   - We would receive a success response "`Deleted branch branch_name (was 5*******9).`"
   - Now, delete the branch remotely `git push origin --delete branch_name`
   - Expected response, `remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done`

If this solves all the issues, then its pretty good. In case if there is another issue..

2. `fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'ORIG_HEAD': cannot lock ref 'ORIG_HEAD': unable to resolve reference 'ORIG_HEAD': reference broken`

   - `rm .git/ORIG_HEAD`
   - `git fetch`
   - `git pull` - which should say `Already up to date.`

Now, we should be able to continue with our work.

Happy coding!